# What are the recommended team layouts?

Tags: overwatch

When choosing heroes, the game tells you whether you have too few or too many of each type of hero, varying depending on your team's role and the gametype, and, maybe, the map. What specific team layouts is the game recommending for each combination?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really, the game only seems to care if you're on Attack or Defense.  On KOTH maps, both teams are Attack.

The warnings I remember seeing are:

For both Attack and Defend:

- No Damage Dealers
- No Supports
- No Tanks
- Too Many Tanks
- Too Many Supports
- Too Many Of The Same Hero

The "Too Many" ones appear if there are 3 or more.

For Attack:

- Few Damage Dealers

  - If you only have one Offense.

For Defense:

- No Defense
- Few Defense

  - If you only have one Defense.
- No Builders

  - If you have no Torbjörn or Symmetra
- No Snipers

  - If you have no Widowmaker or Hanzo

Anyway, what this really boils down to...

- Attack

  - 2 Offense
  - 1 Tank
  - 1 Support
  - The rest filled as appropriate, but keep in mind the Too Many rules
- Defense

  - Widowmaker or Hanzo
  - Torbjörn or Symmetra
  - 1 more Defense if Symmetra is picked above.
  - 1 Tank
  - 1 Support
  - The rest filled as appropriate.